# Image watermarking on specific position in an image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, watermark

Currently I am working with an image processing project in which I need to split the image into several segments and then apply watermark on each of the segment.

I have written a code which divides the image into segments by masking. You may find the code [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/29/accessing-individual-superpixel-segmentations-python/#comment-427438). Now i want to implement watermark on each of these segments. The tutorial for watermarking can be found [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/25/watermarking-images-with-opencv-and-python/).

How am I supposed to do that?
Please help as I am new to OpenCV and Python.
Feel free to ask for any further information needed to solve this.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I am adding some code for your inference:
`

```
segment= 'segment storing location'
image = cv2.imread(image path)
segments = slic(img_as_float(image),compactness= 100.0, n_segments = 10, sigma = 5)    #segmentation of image
row, col, _ = image.shape
for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    # construct a mask for the segment
    print "[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
    mask[segments == segVal] = 255 #masking image with different mask to create unique segments
    bb= (cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask) )
    cv2.imwrite(segment + str(i) + ".png",bb) #save image segments created
```

`

Now after saving the segments, I need to watermark each one of them by calling them one after another. This is the code for watermarking:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
wk= 'D:\\watermark\\wm.png'
input_im= 'D:\\watermark\\input\\image_01.jpg'
op= 'D:\\watermark\\output'
alpha = 0.25
watermark = cv2.imread(wk, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
(wH, wW) = watermark.shape[:2]
image = cv2.imread(input_im)
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
image = np.dstack([image, np.ones((h, w), dtype="uint8") * 255])
overlay = np.zeros((h, w, 4), dtype="uint8")
overlay[h - wH - 500:h - 500, w - wW - 500:w - 500] = watermark #This is the line where we can set the watermark's coordinates
output = image.copy()
cv2.addWeighted(overlay,alpha, output, 1.0, 0, output)
filename = input_im[input_im.rfind(os.path.sep) + 1:]
p = os.path.sep.join((op, filename))
cv2.imwrite(p, output)
```

[image: This is the original image]
   [image: This is one of its segments]
 Now how can I extract the coordinates of this segment in order to watermark it?

### Edit

This is what I get when the lines

```
`cv2.circle(im, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
 cv2.putText(im, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
 cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2`
```

are kept outside the loop:
[image: uncoordinated centre]

And this is what I get when they are executed within the loop:[image: Looped centres]

Comment: You need to create a MCVE (see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). External links to code resources are not useful.

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I have added some more info. Please check.

Comment: Well done. Once you've saved those segments, you have n images (one per segment) with the same dimension of the original one, am I right? 
If you don't have metadata (for example: a log file with a serialization of `mask` content, which could lead to find the segment coordinates), you'll need to find the coordinates by searching the largest area of pixels with values `!= 0`. 
Does this sound good to you?

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista I have the coordinates for the masked content. But how  to implement watermark onto that coordinate area?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the countour of the image (I've downloaded your segment image to try this), then compute the center of the contour.
To find the contour, you need to convert the image to gray scale and threshold it, dividing totally black pixels (black background) from non-black ones (your segment).

#### Finding the center of the segment

The only assumption I've made is that the pixel values of your segments are different from 0 (total black). This assumption may be invalid but, since you're working with photos of natural landscape (like the one you posted) this should not be a problem.

Feel free to ask for further details.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('try.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,1,255,0)  # Threshold to highlight non black pixels
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
  # compute the center of the contour
  M = cv2.moments(c)
  cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
  cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

  # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
  cv2.drawContours(im, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
  cv2.circle(im, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
  cv2.putText(im, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

  # show the image
  cv2.imshow("Image", im)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is what I get:
[image: Drawing of countours and text centering into them]

#### Placing the watermark

Let's say you have the coordinates of the center of the segment region. Knowing the size of the watermark you can convert them coordinates locating the point of the image where to put the left upper corner of the watermark. In this example I assume that them are `(x=10,y=10)`.

I've reused the last image you posted (I'm not drawing the contours, just the watermark).

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv

# Coordinates where to put the watermark (left upper corner)
cy = 10
cx = 10

# Reading the image
image = cv.imread("try.png")
(h,w) = image.shape[:2]
image = np.dstack([image, np.ones((h, w), dtype="uint8") * 255])

# Reading the watermark
watermark = cv.imread("watermark.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
(wH, wW) = watermark.shape[:2]
(B, G, R, A) = cv.split(watermark)
B = cv.bitwise_and(B, B, mask=A)
G = cv.bitwise_and(G, G, mask=A)
R = cv.bitwise_and(R, R, mask=A)
watermark = cv.merge([B, G, R, A])

# Creating the image's overlay with the watermark
overlay = np.zeros((h, w, 4), dtype="uint8")
overlay[cy:wH + cy, cx:wW + cx] = watermark

# Applying the overlay
output = image.copy()
cv.addWeighted(overlay, 0.4, output, 1.0, 0, output)

cv.imshow("out", output)
cv.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so when i tried to run this code with some moderations (to make it compatible for my Open CV version), I did not get the exact output as yours.The center dot is being displayed on the top right corner of the contour. Can you please edit your code so that I may get to know which part is in the for loop and which isn't. Because if this line `cv2.putText(im, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)` is kept inside the loop, numerous centres get printed on the image.

Comment: Hey for your information, I am using python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.9

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you get instead of my result?

Comment: I've included you're edit in your question (appending that to my answer would be a bit confusing). It seems that your second segment is suffering of fragmentation (or something like that). My suggestion is to get only the greater area from the list of the described contour. Let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: By the way, could you provide the second segment image without the green contour?

Comment: I do not need to mark the boundaries of the contour. I just need to set watermark inside the boundaries of the contour. Kindly help me with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147169/discussion-between-ilario-pierbattista-and-ambika-saxena).